# Can you access instance fields from RoleEnvironment.OnRoleChanging event handler?

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, azure-worker-roles

I'm trying to figure out how azure worker roles initiate RoleEnvironment events and how this affects field access.

With reference to my below code sample, my understanding is that:

1. The RoleEnvironmentChanging and RoleEnvironmentChanged event handlers will be run in the context of the thread that initiates the events
2. The event thread will be different than the thread being blocked by the AutoResetEvent

Does this mean that RoleEnvironmentChanged and OnStop will not be able to reference the instance field _someClass, would I have to make it static? Or do the event handlers have a closure around the instance variables?

Here is a simplified example:

```
public abstract class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _eventHandler = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    private SomeClass _someClass;

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        RoleEnvironment.Changing += RoleEnvironmentChanging;
        RoleEnvironment.Changed += RoleEnvironmentChanged;

        _someClass = new SomeClass();

        return base.OnStart();
    }

    public override void OnStop()
    {
        // Tell the other class to stop
        _someClass.Stop();

        base.OnStop();
    }

    public override void Run()
    {
        // Start some process in another class that executes on a different thread internally. 
        _someClass.Run()

        _eventHandler.WaitOne(); // Wait, so the method doesn't return and the role restart.

        base.Run();
    }

    private void RoleEnvironmentChanging(object sender, RoleEnvironmentChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = false // Never restart the role (just for this example)
    }

    void RoleEnvironmentChanged(object sender, RoleEnvironmentChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _SomeClass.Refresh() // Just proving I can call this variable from here.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2 statements are correct (the event handler running on a different thread than your Run() method), but that doesn't have anything to do with accessing the member variables of your WorkerRole class.  The code in the event handlers are instance methods, not static methods, so they are able to access the members of the class.